# Word Replacement In Python

Tags: python-3.x, text

I am working with 4000 character text strings containing customer feedback information. The information is prepared by an employee and is littered with jargon such as product codes. I need to expand these product codes. I am currently leveraging off some code used in Sarkar (2016) that expanded contractions.

The majority of the time the code works although there will be instances where it does not. Best show the code to explain what is happening.

```
ABBREVIATION_MAP = {
 "xxxx" : "Product X",
 "yyyy" : "Product Y",
 "zzzz" : "Product Z"
 }

def expand_abbreviations(sentence, abbreviation_mapping):
    abbreviations_pattern = re.compile('({})'.format('|'.join(abbreviation_mapping.keys())),
                                      flags=re.DOTALL)

def expand_match(abbreviation):
    match=abbreviation.group(0)
    first_char = match[0]
    expanded_abbreviation = abbreviation_mapping.get(match)\
                            if abbreviation_mapping.get(match)\
                            else abbreviation_mapping.get(match.lower())
    expanded_abbreviation = first_char+expanded_abbreviation[1:]
    return expanded_abbreviation

    expanded_sentence = abbreviations_pattern.sub(expand_match, sentence)
    return expanded_sentence


df1['after'] = df1['before'].apply(lambda x: expand_abbreviations(x, ABBREVIATION_MAP))
```

If we look at the conversion for xxxx to Product x, 90% the time it works.

In some records however it remains xxxx.

Sometimes I get xxxx converted to xroduct X. Something for yyyy, sometimes I get yroduct Y.

I've experimented with using alternatives to 'xxxx' -> ' xxxx', 'xxxx ' and ' xxxx ' to no avail.

I've looked at the positioning of the word requiring conversion within the test string (e.g. start, middle, end) and there are no hints as to why the code doesn't work in all instances.

If the xxxx occurs twice in a string, sometimes both are converted, sometimes one, sometimes neither.

Any help would be appreciated. In your reply, please consider I am a 20 year SAS user, 4 week Python user, you will need to dumb it down.

Thanks.

Comment: expanded_abbreviation = first_char+expanded_abbreviation[1:]



This code says to take X from the matched word and put it as x+roductX 
. Hence prints xroductX as expected. 
You can instead removed the above line from your code. Run it and let know if you find the issue again.

Comment: Thanks Jim. If I had spent more time looking at code and thinking about it I should have found that. Shame on me. Sincere thanks for responding, appreciate it.

Comment: Don't be hard on yourself. This is how I too learned. Happy learning!!